# How to use medianBlur in javaCV

Tags: image, image-processing, javacv

which library do i need to import to use medianBlur? can someone provide a sample code?
 thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cvSmooth(srcImage, smoothImage, CV_MEDIAN, 3, 0, 0, 0);
```

3 is the kernal size

Comment: Can you please tell me what are the packages we have to import to use this method?

Comment: `com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*` and
`com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*`

Comment: what is smoothImage?